# Clojure array of maps

Tags: clojure

I am trying to model this kind of data in `Clojure`

```
name: foo    data: bar
name: stack  data: overflow
name: tess   data: ting
```

I thought about using a map, but you can't have duplicated keys in there so that wouldn't work.

Is it possible to have an array of maps, similar to:

```
[{name: foo,    data: bar} 
{name: stack,  data: overflow} 
{name: tess,   data: ting}]
```

if it is, how would you access the data. for example, how would you access `data: overflow`

would you have to use a nested `get` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `{:name "foo" :data "overflow"}`, this is EDN, not JSON;

Second, yes, it's ok to `(def map-array [{:name "foo"} {:name "bar"}])`

To get access to fields you can use `get` and `get-in`:
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in.

```
(get-in map-array [1 :name])
=> "bar"
```

You can also use `filter` function in such way:

```
(first (filter #(= "foo" (:name %)) map-array))
=> {:name "foo"}
```

EDIT:
If you want to get rid of `filter` to and get constant access time to your  maps, you should use some kind of uniq ID:

```
(def map-array {:id1 {:name "foo"}
                :id2 {:name "bar"}})
(get-in map-array [:id1 :name])
=> "foo"

;; using threading macro and keyword special power:
(-> map-array :id2 :name)
=> "bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I am missing something, but it looks as-if you are reinventing a map where instead of *keys* and *values* you want to have *names* and *data*. For example, the following is sufficient to model your map:

```
(get {"foo" "bar" "stack" "overflow" "tess" "ting"} "stack")
=> "overflow"
```

Now, if your data is more complex, you can certainly store a map under an certain key.
In other words, you build a map where the key is the name associated with each data. Suppose you have a vector of such things:

```
(def data [{:name "foo"   :data "bar"} 
           {:name "stack" :data "overflow"} 
           {:name "tess"  :data "ting"}])
```

In order to have the corresponding map, you can do:

```
(reduce (fn [m d] (assoc m (:name d) d)) {} data)
```

... which gives:

```
{"tess"  {:name "tess" , :data "ting"}, 
 "stack" {:name "stack", :data "overflow"}, 
 "foo"   {:name "foo"  , :data "bar"}}
```